# Making an in depth "quiz" for Dungeons and Dragons

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, counter

I've been struggling to make a quiz with a randomized question bank where the questions will be able to increase a number of different counters (each question will be different in what they return). Below i show what i have so far and two example questions with only a few of the "counter increases" that they will ultimately have. Is there a way to put the questions i have into a bank so each time the quiz is run it has a different 20 questions from a bank of 50 or so?

```
barbarian_count = 0
bard_count = 0
cleric_count = 0
druid_count = 0
fighter_count = 0
monk_count = 0
paladin_count = 0
ranger_count = 0
rogue_count = 0
sorcerer_count = 0
warlock_count = 0
wizard_count = 0

STR_count = 0
DEX_count = 0
CON_count = 0
INT_count = 0
WIS_count = 0
CHA_count = 0

law_count = 0
chaos_count = 0
neutrallc_count = 0

good_count = 0
neutralge_count = 0
evil_count = 0

Acolyte_count = 0
Charlatan_count = 0
CriminalSpy_count = 0
Entertainer_count = 0
Folkhero_count = 0
Gladiator_count = 0
Guildartmerchant_count = 0
hermit_count = 0
knight_count = 0
noble_count = 0
outlander_count = 0
pirate_count = 0
sage_count = 0
sailor_count = 0
soldier_count = 0
urchin_count = 0


q1_answer = input ("Passion or Reason? \na) Passion \nb) Reason\n")

if q1_answer.lower() == "a":
    barbarian_count += 1
  bard_count += 1
  chaos_count += 1
elif q1_answer.lower() == "b":
    wizard_count += 1
  law_count += 1
else:
    print("sorry, try again.")


q2 = q2_answer = input ("Fame or Honor? \na) Fame \nb) Honor\n")

if q2_answer.lower() == "a":
    bard_count += 1
elif q2_answer.lower() == "b":
    paladin_count += 1
else:
    print("sorry, try again.")




if barbarian_count > wizard_count and barbarian_count > bard_count and barbarian_count > paladin_count:
    print("You have the heart of a barbarian")
elif wizard_count > barbarian_count and wizard_count > bard_count and wizard_count > paladin_count:
    print("You have the heart of a wizard")
elif bard_count > wizard_count and bard_count > paladin_count and bard_count > barbarian_count:
  print("You have the heart of a bard")
elif paladin_count > wizard_count and paladin_count > barbarian_count and paladin_count > bard_count:
  print("You have the heart of a paladin")

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

I tried making a list with something like

```
question_bank = [
  {
    'q1 = [q1_answer = input ("Passion or Reason? \na) Passion \nb) Reason\n")

if q1_answer.lower() == "a":
    barbarian_count += 1
elif q1_answer.lower() == "b":
    wizard_count += 1
else:
    print("sorry, try again."]'
  },
  {
    'q2 = q2_answer = input ("Fame or Honor? \na) Fame \nb) Honor\n")

if q2_answer.lower() == "a":
    bard_count += 1
elif q2_answer.lower() == "b":
    paladin_count += 1
else:
    print("sorry, try again.")'
  }
]
```

But have realized lists do not work like that, i think.

Any advice? I was hoping i could put each full script for each question into a list so i could use the "import random" and random.choice or random.sample to then pull the full question's script.

Comment: Your ideas area good, you just need to google how lists work. `questions = ['What is your name?', 'What is your favourite colour?', 'What is the air speed of a swallow?']` is a valid list. You can then choose questions by getting items from that list like this: `question[0]` which would return `What is your name?`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That helps me get the list format down. How can i tie question[0] to its answers, and the numerous counter += 1 for each answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `random.sample` is a good way of picking random questions from a master list of questions. Here's what I came up with:

The different character types have turned into an `enum` (enumeration). One big advantage of this approach is that it prevents you from "stringifying" things. Instead of hardcoding string-literals in your code any time you need to print or perform a comparison with a character type, you can use an enum instance instead.

You have a `collections.Counter` (which, in our case, is really only a dictionary where the key is a `Character` enum instance, and the associated value is the point count or tally from the quiz). You don't have to use a `collections.Counter`, a plain python dictionary would do just as well. Either way it is preferable to creating lots of individual counter variables.

`queries` is a list of `Query` objects (a `Query` is what I've decided to call a question). This is basically your master list of all possible questions, any one of which can appear in the quiz later. A single `Query` object consists of a `prompt` string which represents the actual question to be asked. It also contains a list of `Choice` objects named `choices`. These represent all the possible valid choices / answers / response that the user is allowed to make in response to this query.

A `Choice` object consists of some `text`, which is the text to be displayed, as well as a `character_type` variable, which is going to be a `Character` enum instance. If the user selects this choice, this enum instance will increment the associated count in the `counter` object.

Both `Query` and `Choice` are just simple `collections.namedtuple`s, because I didn't feel like making classes for them.

After defining the `queries` list comes the actual quiz. We pick some number of random queries from our `queries` list using `random.sample`, and then do the following for each query:

1. Print the current query's prompt.
2. Display all the available options for that query
3. Get user input (enter a loop which only terminates if the user
   enters valid input).
4. Increment the counter based on the user's choice.
5. Start the loop over and do all that again for the next query until
   there are no more randomly picked queries left.

Finally, we print the result of the quiz. I realize you have a ton more character types, and even other attributes like strength and dexterity that I didn't even take into account. Hopefully this is useful and not overwhelming.

```
def main():

    from enum import Enum, auto
    from collections import Counter, namedtuple

    from random import sample

    class Character(Enum):
        Barbarian = auto()
        Bard = auto()
        Cleric = auto()

    counter = Counter()

    Choice = namedtuple("Choice", ["text", "character_type"])
    Query = namedtuple("Query", ["prompt", "choices"])

    queries = [
        Query("Battleaxe or Lute?", [
            Choice("Battleaxe (grunt)", Character.Barbarian),
            Choice("The Lute! Oh how I love singing!", Character.Bard)]),
        Query("Do you prefer healing people or singing to them?", [
            Choice("I prefer to heal people", Character.Cleric),
            Choice("I LOVE SINGING", Character.Bard)]),
        Query("Do you fight against Man or the Undead?", [
            Choice("Me fight Man (grunt)", Character.Barbarian),
            Choice("I prefer to fight the undead", Character.Cleric)]),
        Query("Sing and dance, heal people, or wage war?", [
            Choice("I'LL SING!!", Character.Bard),
            Choice("I'd prefer to heal people", Character.Cleric),
            Choice("Me wage war (ugh)", Character.Barbarian)])
    ]

    number_of_random_queries = 3
    for current_query in sample(queries, k=number_of_random_queries):
        print(current_query.prompt)
        for choice_index, choice in enumerate(current_query.choices, start=1):
            print(f"    {choice_index}.) {choice.text}")
        # Get user input, stay in this loop until they enter something valid.
        while True:
            user_input = input("Enter your choice: ")
            try:
                user_choice_index = int(user_input)-1
                assert user_choice_index >= 0
                user_choice = current_query.choices[user_choice_index]
            except (ValueError, AssertionError, KeyError):
                # Either the input was not a number, or the number was an invalid index.
                continue
            else:
                break
        # Increment the counter / tally for the associated character type.
        counter.update({user_choice.character_type})
        print("-" * 20)

    # Print the final result.
    character_type = counter.most_common(n=1)[0][0]
    print(f"You have the heart of a {character_type.name}.")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Sing and dance, heal people, or wage war?
    1.) I'LL SING!!
    2.) I'd prefer to heal people
    3.) Me wage war (ugh)
Enter your choice: 1
--------------------
Do you prefer healing people or singing to them?
    1.) I prefer to heal people
    2.) I LOVE SINGING
Enter your choice: 2
--------------------
Do you fight against Man or the Undead?
    1.) Me fight Man (grunt)
    2.) I prefer to fight the undead
Enter your choice: 2
--------------------
You have the heart of a Bard.
```

**EDIT - Just thought I should edit this post, explain a few things and make my original answer less complex.**

Forget all this `def main`, `collections.Counter` and `enum.auto` stuff for right now.

Starting out, you may be tempted to write something like this (as you have):

```
barbarian_count = 0
bard_count = 0
cleric_count = 0

# ...

if barbarian_count > bard_count and barbarian_count > cleric_count:
    print("You're a barbarian!")
elif bard_count > barbarian_count and bard_count > cleric_count:
    print("You're a bard!")
elif cleric_count > barbarian_count and cleric_count > bard_count:
    print("You're a cleric!")
else:
    # ...
```

Which is not bad - it's just not very easy to maintain and extend - maybe you've already discovered that. For example, this code only works for three unique character types (barbarian, bard and cleric). What if I want to add a new character type to the project? I'll have to change my code to this:

```
barbarian_count = 0
bard_count = 0
cleric_count = 0
druid_count = 0

# ...

if barbarian_count > bard_count and barbarian_count > cleric_count and barbarian_count > druid_count:
    print("You're a barbarian!")
elif bard_count > barbarian_count and bard_count > cleric_count and bard_count > druid_count:
    print("You're a bard!")
elif cleric_count > barbarian_count and cleric_count > bard_count and cleric_count > druid_count:
    print("You're a cleric!")
elif druid_count > barbarian_count and druid_count > bard_count and druid_count > cleric_count:
    print("You're a druid!")
else:
    # ...
```

I had to add a new counter variable, extend the conditions for all of my existing if-statements, and even add a whole new if-statement which is just as long as the others. You can imagine how things can quickly get out of hand if you try to add more character types using this approach. You may be tempted to copy-paste if-statements because you don't want to type everything manually, but in my experience that just leads to bugs in your code (because you might forget to change a variable name in one of the conditions, for example).

That's why I suggest using an enum to define the possible character types. Just a quick introduction to enums:

```
from enum import Enum

class CharacterType(Enum):
    Barbarian = 0
    Bard = 1
    Cleric = 2

for character_type in CharacterType:
    print(character_type)
```

Output:

```
CharacterType.Barbarian
CharacterType.Bard
CharacterType.Cleric
>>>
```

You can see I've changed the name of the enum from `Character` to `CharacterType`, which I think is a bit more appropriate. This snippet is just meant to demonstrate that you can iterate over all possible enum states (in our case the unique character types) in a simple for-loop. These are not strings that are being printed in the for-loop by the way - `character_type` is an instance of a `CharacterType` enum.

Take a look at the `CharacterType` enum. I'm setting `Barbarian = 0`, `Bard = 1` and `Cleric = 2`. These values don't have anything to do with the count or tally. These are just unique values - think of them as unique IDs. They don't even need to be integers - they could be anything, like strings:

```
from enum import Enum

class CharacterType(Enum):
    Barbarian = "Hello"
    Bard = "World"
    Cleric = "WUIAHkjahdkjsh893y724uhj"

for character_type in CharacterType:
    print(character_type)
```

If I run this code, I get the same exact output. The associated value to any one CharacterType just has to be a unique object - which is why it's common practice to simply number them starting at 0 or 1 (or use `enum.auto` which picks unique IDs for us).

Now, I'd like to have a way of introducing some kind of counters or counter variables - one for each of my character types. Instead of creating separate variables, we can create a plain old python dictionary, where the key is the character type, and the associated value is the count or tally for that particular character type.

```
from enum import Enum

class CharacterType(Enum):
    Barbarian = 0
    Bard = 1
    Cleric = 2

counter = {}

for character_type in CharacterType:
    counter.update({character_type: 0})

for character_type, count in counter.items():
    print(f"The current count for {character_type.name} is {count}")
```

Output:

```
The current count for Barbarian is 0
The current count for Bard is 0
The current count for Cleric is 0
```

Under our `CharacterType` enum we create an empty dictionary called `counter`. Then we have the same for-loop as before where we iterate over all the different character types in our enum. However, instead of printing the character types, we simply add new key-value pairs to our dictionary. Basically, we're just initializing our dictionary so that the count / tally for every single character type starts out at zero. The second for-loop is just there for us to verify that the dictionary has three key-value pairs - one for each character type, and that their associated values (counts) are zero.

If you're interested in sticking with my initial approach for constructing the questions and responses, this is the part where you'd create the named tuples. Don't forget to `from collections import namedtuple` at the top of your code:

```
Query = namedtuple("Query", ["text", "choices"])
Choice = namedtuple("Choice", ["text", "character_types"])

queries = [

    Query(
        text="Battleaxe or Lute?",
        choices=[

            Choice(
                text="Battleaxe (grunt)",
                character_types=[
                    (CharacterType.Barbarian, 2),
                    (CharacterType.Cleric, 1)
                ]
            ), # First choice ends here

            Choice(
                text="The Lute! Oh how I love singing!",
                character_types=[
                    (CharacterType.Bard, 2)
                ]
            ) # Second choice ends here

        ] # List of choices ends here
    ), # First Query ends here

    Query(
        text="Do you prefer healing people or singing to them?",
        choices=[

            Choice(
                text="I prefer to heal people",
                character_types=[
                    (CharacterType.Cleric, 1)
                ]
            ), # First choice ends here

            Choice(
                text="I LOVE SINGING",
                character_types=[
                    (CharacterType.Bard, 2)
                ]
            ) # Second choice ends here
        ] # List of choices ends here
    ) # Second Query ends here
] # List of all queries ends here
```

I've changed a few things. A Query has a `text` string (instead of a `prompt` string, I just changed the name), and a list of `Choice` objects named `choices`.

A `Choice` object also has a `text` string. However, the property that used to be called `character_type` is now `character_types` - this indicates that this is meant to be a list of things, rather than on single thing. I made this change to support affecting the counts of multiple character types by selecting certain choices.

Then there's the `queries` list, which is a list of `Query` objects. There's only two Query objects this time instead of four, because it would have taken a long time to type - it's just for demonstration. I've also added indentation where I think it might be helpful, just to see where one object begins and another ends. I know it might seem like we're not really saving much typing by using this approach, but a data-driven approach like this tends to pay off - doing a bit more typing before the actual interesting stuff happens can save us lots of headaches and typing later on.

Take a look at the first `Choice` of the first `Query`, specifically the `character_types` property:

```
               character_types=[
                    (CharacterType.Barbarian, 2),
                    (CharacterType.Cleric, 1)
                ]
```

This is different from what we were doing before. `character_types` is now a list of tuples. There are two tuples. The first element of each tuple is the character type that is affected, and the second element is an integer which is the value by which to increment the counter for that character type. In this case, selecting this choice would increment the Barbarian count by 2, and the Cleric count by 1. This is how we can support incrementing multiple counts by different values.

Since you mentioned wanting a pool of 50 potential queries in the end, I would consider putting all of your questions in a separate text file (something like a JSON compliant format might be especially cute), just so that you're not writing this huge list right in your source code. Your code would then simply read the file during runtime and load the questions.

Here's the rest of the code. Again, some things have changed - the number of random queries is set to just one, because I only have two in my pool of possible queries. I've added comments where I think they might be helpful, and I've used if-statements instead of exceptions to validate the input. Updating the counter has changed, too, since we're not using a `collections.Counter` object anymore, and also because we'd like to support updating multiple character type counters at once. The final step of determining which counter was the highest has also changed. Also, don't forget to do `from random import sample`.

```
number_of_random_queries = 1
for current_query in sample(queries, k=number_of_random_queries):

    # Print the current query's text
    print(current_query.text)

    # Print all the available options for the current query
    for choice_index, choice in enumerate(current_query.choices, start=1):
        print(f"    {choice_index}.) {choice.text}")

    # Get user input
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter your choice: ")
        if not user_input.isdigit():
            # User input is not a number, ask them for input again
            continue
        user_choice_index = int(user_input)-1
        if not (0 <= user_choice_index <= len(current_query.choices)-1):
            # User input was a number, but it was an invalid index, ask them for input again
            continue
        user_choice = current_query.choices[user_choice_index]
        # Terminate the input loop
        break

    # We now have the user's selection (Choice object). Now update the appropriate counter(s)
    for character_type, increment_value in user_choice.character_types:
        old_counter_value = counter[character_type]
        new_counter_value = old_counter_value + increment_value
        counter.update({character_type: new_counter_value})
    print("-" * 20)

# The quiz for-loop is now over
# Determine which counter has the highest value

character_type, value = max(counter.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1])
print(f"You have the heart of a {character_type.name} with {value} point(s)!")
```

To summarize: Even though it doesn't seem like we've saved much typing, we actually have. You are now free to add as many unique character types to the `CharacterType` enum, and you will not have to make any other changes to the rest of your code - with the possible exception of the queries list, since you may want to add more questions for the new character types.

**ONE MORE EDIT** - I was trying to avoid having this get too dense - sorry about that. You have a single counter dictionary whose keys are enums and the associated values are dicionaries that do the actual counting.

```
from enum import Enum
from collections import namedtuple
from random import sample


class CharacterType(Enum):
    Barbarian = 0
    Bard = 1
    Cleric = 2

class CharacterAttribute(Enum):
    Strength = 0
    Dexterity = 1
    Intelligence = 2

class CharacterAlignment(Enum):
    Chaotic = 0
    Neutral = 1
    Lawful = 2

counters = {}

for CharacterProperty in [CharacterType, CharacterAttribute, CharacterAlignment]:
    counters.update({CharacterProperty: {}})
    for character_property in CharacterProperty:
        counters[CharacterProperty].update({character_property: 0})

Query = namedtuple("Query", ["text", "choices"])
Choice = namedtuple("Choice", ["text", "types", "attributes", "alignments"])

queries = [

    Query(
        text="Battleaxe or Lute?",
        choices=[

            Choice(
                text="Battleaxe (grunt)",
                types=[
                    (CharacterType.Barbarian, 2),
                    (CharacterType.Cleric, 1)
                ],
                attributes=[
                    (CharacterAttribute.Strength, 3),
                    (CharacterAttribute.Dexterity, 1)
                ],
                alignments=[
                    (CharacterAlignment.Chaotic, 1)
                ]
            ), # First choice ends here

            Choice(
                text="The Lute! Oh how I love singing!",
                types=[
                    (CharacterType.Bard, 2)
                ],
                attributes = [
                    (CharacterAttribute.Intelligence, 1)
                ],
                alignments = [
                    (CharacterAlignment.Lawful, 4)
                ]
            ) # Second choice ends here

        ] # List of choices ends here
    ), # First Query ends here

    Query(
        text="Do you prefer healing people or singing to them?",
        choices=[

            Choice(
                text="I prefer to heal people",
                types=[
                    (CharacterType.Cleric, 1)
                ],
                attributes=[
                    (CharacterAttribute.Intelligence, 2)
                ],
                alignments=[
                    (CharacterAlignment.Lawful, 2)
                ]
            ), # First choice ends here

            Choice(
                text="I LOVE SINGING",
                types=[
                    (CharacterType.Bard, 2)
                ],
                attributes=[
                    (CharacterAttribute.Intelligence, 2),
                    (CharacterAttribute.Dexterity, 2)
                ],
                alignments=[
                    (CharacterAlignment.Lawful, 1)
                ]
            ) # Second choice ends here
        ] # List of choices ends here
    ) # Second Query ends here
] # List of all queries ends here


number_of_random_queries = 1
for current_query in sample(queries, k=number_of_random_queries):

    # Print the current query's text
    print(current_query.text)

    # Print all the available options for the current query
    for choice_index, choice in enumerate(current_query.choices, start=1):
        print(f"    {choice_index}.) {choice.text}")

    # Get user input
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter your choice: ")
        if not user_input.isdigit():
            # User input is not a number, ask them for input again
            continue
        user_choice_index = int(user_input)-1
        if not (0 <= user_choice_index <= len(current_query.choices)-1):
            # User input was a number, but it was an invalid index, ask them for input again
            continue
        user_choice = current_query.choices[user_choice_index]
        # Terminate the input loop
        break

    # We now have the user's selection (Choice object). Now update the appropriate counter(s)
    choice_lists = [user_choice.types, user_choice.attributes, user_choice.alignments]

    for CharacterProperty, choice_list in zip(counters, choice_lists):
        for character_property, increment_value in choice_list:
            old_counter_value = counters[CharacterProperty][character_property]
            new_counter_value = old_counter_value + increment_value
            counters[CharacterProperty].update({character_property: new_counter_value})
    print("-" * 20)

# The quiz for-loop is now over
# Determine which counter has the highest value

def get_max_property(dictionary):
    return max(dictionary.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1])

character_type, character_type_points = get_max_property(counters[CharacterType])
character_attribute, character_attribute_points = get_max_property(counters[CharacterAttribute])
character_alignment, character_alignment_points = get_max_property(counters[CharacterAlignment])

print(f"You have the heart of a {character_type.name} with {character_type_points} point(s)!")
print(f"Your highest attribute is {character_attribute.name} with {character_attribute_points} points.")
print(f"Your alignment: {character_alignment.name}")
```

Comment: it is a little overwhelming but INCREDIBLY helpful. Thank you so much. I just spent the last hour digesting it all. If i want to be able to have a single answer increase multiple counters, is that possible? I'm not sure how to set it to accept multiple "character_type (or other attributes that i can make)" after the text of a query. –

EDIT: I think a simple "and" between multiple Character.type is working.

Comment: How do i add another separate counter? You have a "counter = Counter()" line, and down at the bottom you have "counter.update({user_choice.character_type})" and "character_type = counter.most_common(n=1)[0][0]"

If i want to have the same thing but for another class of enums, like STR DEX or CON, or alignment (Choatic, Neutral, Lawful), how can i make it count those separate? @user1

Comment: I'm not supposed to use comments to say thank you, but this is an insane amount of work and it is exactly what i needed. It makes perfect sense and is above and beyond what i expected. Thank you so much. @user1

Comment: No worries, glad it's helpful!